# JavaScript apply reading strings as arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, apply

I was trying to use the apply method following an introductory course, and found some weird behaviour - that it read strings as arrays of characters, rather than reading an array of strings.

```
var john = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 26,
  job: 'teacher',
  listActivities: function(actList){
    for (var i=0; i < actList.length; i++){
      console.log("I enjoy "+actList[i]);
    }
  },
  presentation: function(style, timeOfDay){
    if(style=="formal"){
      console.log('Good ' + timeOfDay + ' Ladies and Gentlemen! I\'m ' +this.name+', I\'m '+this.age+' and I\'m a '+this.job);
    }
    if(style=="friendly"){
      console.log('Hi! How\'s it going? I\'m ' + this.name +', I\'m '+this.age+' and I\'m a '+this.job +'. Have a great '+timeOfDay);
    }
  }
};

var emily = {
  name: 'Emily',
  age: '35',
  'job': 'designer'
};

john.presentation('formal','morning');

john.presentation.call(emily, 'friendly', 'afternoon');
john.listActivities(["golf", "Stroking animals", "Monty Python"]);
john.listActivities.apply(emily,["knitting", "cooking", "Monty Python"]);
```

John's call to list activities works as expected. The apply call yielded

```
I like k
I like n
```

... etc up to the end of the first word. I know that strings are commonly implemented as arrays of characters, but I don't understand why they are accessed so differently here. What's going on and how could I work around it?

Comment: A string is seen as an array-like object because it has a `.length` and numeric indices. As such, you can iterate it in a loop. The `apply` method spreads the array of values out into individual arguments, so you're referencing `"knitting"` at the `actList` parameter.

Comment: @squint: It's not even that. It's just the OP misunderstanding what `apply` does. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That would be the last sentence in my comment. ;-)

Comment: Yes, the tutorial I was following was worded slightly ambiguously about apply expecting an array as an argument- this is much clearer now! Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the `listActivities()` function with `.apply()`:

```
john.listActivities.apply(emily,["knitting", "cooking", "Monty Python"]);
```

That means that the first argument, `actList`, will be `"knitting"`. Your code treats the argument like an array, and when you do that to a string you get the list of characters in the string.

Your function appears to expect an array, so there's no reason to use `.apply()` to call it:

```
john.listActivities(["knitting", "cooking", "Monty Python"]);
```

The function doesn't rely on `this` anyway, so there's really no reason to use either `.call()` or `.apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `apply` expects you to pass your parameters to it packaged up in an array. So if you are passing an array to it you need to change the call to `apply` like this

```
john.listActivities.apply(emily,[["knitting", "cooking", "Monty Python"]]);
```

[Learn more about apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 1):

You have only one parameter listed at `listActivities`. You can use rest parameter to return expected result

```
  listActivities: function(...actList) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < actList.length; i++) {
      console.log("I enjoy " + actList[i]);
    }
  }
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ktzrnsph/